# Img position discrepancies between IE and firefox, google chrome, etc

Tags: html, image, position

I am trying to embed a youtube video, but make it look like its on the image of a tv.  It looks the way i want it to in IE, but on firefox and Google Chrome, it does not.

```
#youtubeBG img {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;

}
<div id="youtubeBG" style="width:1000px; height:700px; text-align:center;"><img       src="images/4.png"/>
<span class='embed-youtube' style='text-align: left; display: block; position: absolute; top: 305px; left: 382px; width: 786px; height: 514px;'>    <iframe class='youtube-player' type='text/html' width='750' height='528.3' src='' frameborder='0'></iframe>
</span></div>
```

Comment: in IE the embeded video lines up over the screen of the tv perfectly(both centered on page), but in FF and Chrome, the tv img is not centered, and the video is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a lot of unnecessary style to achieve what you want.
Generally width:100% is not a good idea as every browser seems to calculate and render this it's own way.

Here is what I would recommend: http://fiddle.jshell.net/iGanja/PJwD2/

You will notice I added borders for visual reference since I don't have your image available. You basically will want to adjust the -20px to match your background image.

Hope this helps.

```
#youtubeBG img {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

<div id="youtubeBG" style="border: 1px solid black; width:1000px; height:550px; text-align:center;">
    <img src="images/4.png"/>
    <div class='embed-youtube' style='border: 1px solid red; width: 786px; height: 514px; margin:-20px auto;'>
        <iframe class='youtube-player' type='text/html' width='750' height='528.3' src='' frameborder='0'></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the image behind the embeded video is 950px X 537px, but switching between browsers it seems to resize. so now i have another issue. lol i'm sorry, i'm still relatively new at all this. the embeded video needs to be centered in the image, and with your code, it stacks static.

Comment: @user2320427, That is happening because of your width:100%. IE vs other browsers renders this differently. What I would recommend is changing the -20px to -537px and that should line your video right on top of your image. If your tv image has some top portion you don't want to overlap, then just reduce the -537 to some smaller number until it lines up the way you want.

Comment: @user2320427 I updated the fiddle to use those dimensions you gave. http://fiddle.jshell.net/iGanja/PJwD2/2/
Also, older versions of IE like text-align:center;